# Eclipse for Java is great! Is there an analogon for python?

Tags: python, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

I want to get serious with python and write bigger projects. And for that I need an IDE, that helps me concentrate more on thinking and less on coding.

Until know I used TextMate (Mac), vim, and notepad++ (Windows). editors like these are good to grab a file for quick modifications, but for me they don't seem appropriate for whole projects. (This is how **I** feel about it, no offense...) :-)

I want to use a webframework (perhaps Django?) to develop a webpage in python.

Desirable features are:

1. Code completion
2. Refactoring
3. Code Folding
4. Proposal of methods and attributes for standard modules and classes by the IDE
5. It would be great if it comes with a little documentation.
6. SVN would be great too!
7. Not necessary, but it would be great if it would work on Linux and Windows (and Mac)

Below the line I am looking for an IDE, that makes me as happy coding in python as eclipse does, when I code in Java.

Any recommendations? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PyDev](http://pydev.org/) is a Python IDE based on Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

[Eclipse supports Python development](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EclipsePythonIntegration).

Comment: This link is to a french website. I don't speak french. ;-)

Comment: @Aufwind: Maybe the link has been changed since you tried it, but it looked like English to me.

Comment: Now, it is not french anymore. Thanks. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I did initially put the wrong link.

Answer (score 2):

I recently switch from Eclipse PDT to PHP Storm for my development. I think you should try jetbrain's IDE for Python : http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: It could be free for open source project and the product woth the prize.

Answer (score 1):

With google I found an integretated IDE for Eclipse for Python [IDE](http://pydev.org/).

Answer (score 0):

There is [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) and the lighter, free [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit).